# discord.py check mentioned id with list of id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot would save my id if I type `-afk`, and when another user mentions me, my bot would send message that I'm `afk`.

The problem is that my `if` statements are not working when I'm trying to check mentioned id and id in `afk_list`.

Here's the problem:

```
    async def on_message(self, message):
    mentioned = message.raw_mentions

    if mentioned in afk_list:
        print('Found!!')
        await self.client.say('User is AFK')
```

This is my entire code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

afk_list = []

class Manage:

def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

async def on_message(self, message):
    mentioned = message.raw_mentions

    if mentioned in afk_list:
        print('Found!!')
        await self.client.say('User is AFK')

@commands.command(pass_context = True)
async def afk(self, ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    author = ctx.message.author
    date = datetime.date.today

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.red()
    )
    afk_list.append(ctx.message.author.id)
    embed.add_field(name='**User {} is currently AFK**'.format(author), value='Since ', inline=False)

    await self.client.send_message(channel, embed=embed)

@commands.command()
async def afklist(self):
    #await self.client.say('AFK ID list: ')
    #for name in afk_list:
    #    print('List: {}'.format(name))
    #    await self.client.say(name)
    print(afk_list)

def setup(client):
   client.add_cog(Manage(client))
```

Thank you! I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Message.raw_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.raw_mentions) returns a list. You can use `any(id in afk_list for id in mentioned)` to see if anything from that list is also in `afk_list`.  If you use `Message.mentions` instead, you can also specify which users are afk.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    mentioned = message.mentions

    for user in mentions:
        if user.id in afk_list:
            await self.client.send_message(message.channel, '{} is AFK'.format(user.display_name))
```

You also can't use `Bot.say` outside of commands.

Comment: Thanks it's worked like a charm! One small question, my afk command run twice everytime user run that command, any ideas?

Comment: That may be the `await self.client.process_commands(message)`.  It's necessary if it's your only `on_message` (otherwise commands on't run at all.)  Try removing that line