# How to detect if a specific user is mentioned in discord.py then send a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried reading through the documentation but I'm new to python and don't understand a thing. I'd like my bot to send a message when a user gets mention. For example, when I get mentioned, the bot will respond response A etc. Any thoughts? TIA.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194478/discord-py-check-mentioned-id-with-list-of-id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py check mentioned id with list of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194478/discord-py-check-mentioned-id-with-list-of-id)